# bit-wise operation and strict aliasing

Tags: c++, pointers, bit-manipulation, simd

Bit-wise operation and strict alising

I am trying to write some high-performance functions for bit-based operations that taking the advantage of latest features of hardware, the problem I am facing is:

I want to include a bit-wise count operation, in which case I used Intel `SSE4.2`'s `popcnt` that only accecpt integer type values.

Whilst, if I need to conduct other bitwise logical operations, then `AVX` support 256-bit wide bit-wise logical operations like `VORPD` (instead of `SSE2`'s 128 bit wide bit-wise logical operations), but only on floating data.

Coupling with the fact for bit-wise setting/resetting operations, char is fastest, so I may need at least three types of pointers pointed to the same memory locations: **a char type, a long long** (64-bit integer for optimal bit-wise counting), and **a floating type** pointers, however the co-existence of Integer and floating type of pointers break the strict-aliasing rules.

Any suggestion to working around with this? thanks.

Comment: I've never had problems with strict-aliasing on SIMD datatypes. I bet a lot of compilers have it as an exception and will build around it.

Comment: @Mysticial At the moment strict-alsising rule is not applied so I know many compilers can accept you get 3 types of pointers pointed to the same address, I just want more for future-proof solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `gcc` or `clang` or something that behaves similarly?  They have [`__attribute__((__may_alias__))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) to work around these problems.

Comment: Indeed, `__m256` is defined as a `may_alias` type, and SIMD load/store intrinsics are defined as aliasing-safe.  [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605)