# Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, x86, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, intrinsics

Is it legal to `reinterpret_cast` a `float*` to a `__m256*` and access `float` objects through a different pointer type?

```
constexpr size_t _m256_float_step_sz = sizeof(__m256) / sizeof(float);
alignas(__m256) float stack_store[100 * _m256_float_step_sz ]{};
__m256& hwvec1 = *reinterpret_cast<__m256*>(&stack_store[0 * _m256_float_step_sz]);

using arr_t = float[_m256_float_step_sz];
arr_t& arr1 = *reinterpret_cast<float(*)[_m256_float_step_sz]>(&hwvec1);
```

Do `hwvec1` and `arr1` depend on `undefined behavior`s?

Do they violate strict aliasing rules? [[basic.lval]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#basic.lval-11)

Or there is only one defined way of intrinsic:

```
__m256 hwvec2 = _mm256_load_ps(&stack_store[0 * _m256_float_step_sz]);
_mm256_store_ps(&stack_store[1 * _m256_float_step_sz], hwvec2);
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/uQjp8_)

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't violate strict aliasing rule? In my opinion, your first code violates it. I'd use intrinsics for this, just as you suggest.

Comment: @geza Thank you. I'm just uncertained because the representation underlined is never be accessed as any other type than `float`

Comment: Won't you use it as `__m256` as well? If not, then what's the point? :)

Comment: @geza So in your opinion, does accessing floats that reside inside `__m256` object and within `__m256` lifetime violate strict aliasing rules?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't do it. There is a surely non-violating solution, I'd use load/store intrinsics instead. The only reason to choose reinterpret_cast if for some reason, it is faster. But current compilers are pretty good optimizing these kind of stuff.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ISO C++ doesn't define `__m256`, so we need to look at what *does* define their behaviour on the implementations that support them.

**Intel's intrinsics define vector-pointers like `__m256*` as being allowed to alias anything else, the same way ISO C++ defines `char*` as being allowed to alias.**  (But not vice-versa: it's UB and breaks in practice to point an `int*` at a `__m256i` and deref it.)

So yes, it's safe to dereference a `__m256*` instead of using a `_mm256_load_ps()` aligned-load intrinsic.

But especially for float/double, it's often easier to use the intrinsics because they take care of casting from `float*`, too.  For integers, the AVX512 load/store intrinsics are defined as taking `void*`, but AVX2 and earlier need a cast like `(__m256i*)&arr[i]` which is pretty clunky API design and clutters up code using it.

A few non-AVX512 intrinsics have also been added using `void*` like `movd`/`movq` load/store alignment and aliasing safe intrinsics such as `_mm_loadu_si32(void*)`.  Previously I think Intel assumed you'd use `_mm_cvtsi32_si128` which required getting an `int` loaded safely yourself, which meant using `memcpy` to avoid UB (at least on compilers other than classic ICC and MSVC, if they allow unaligned `int*` as well as not enforcing strict aliasing).  This might have been around the time Intel started looking at migrating to LLVM for ICX/ICPX / OneAPI, and realizing how much of a mess it was to deal with narrow loads on compilers that enforce strict aliasing.

---

To learn some about what the intrinsics API required, we can look at the non-portable implementation details of GCC.  Presumably they inferred from Intel examples or documentation what behaviour was necessary, or some Intel engineers may have sent patches.  (You shouldn't rely on the GCC details because it's not documented and other compilers that implement `__m256` and other intrinsic types might do things differently.  But we can see that GCC had to explicitly allow aliasing that wouldn't otherwise be safe.)

In GCC, this is implemented by defining `__m256` with a `may_alias` attribute:  from gcc7.3's `avxintrin.h` (one of the headers that `<immintrin.h>` includes):

> ```
> /* The Intel API is flexible enough that we must allow aliasing with other
>    vector types, and their scalar components.  */
> typedef float __m256 __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32),
>                                      __may_alias__));
> typedef long long __m256i __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32),
>                                           __may_alias__));
> typedef double __m256d __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32),
>                                        __may_alias__));
>
> /* Unaligned version of the same types.  */
> typedef float __m256_u __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32),
>                                        __may_alias__,
>                                        __aligned__ (1)));
> typedef long long __m256i_u __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32),
>                                             __may_alias__,
>                                             __aligned__ (1)));
> typedef double __m256d_u __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32),
>                                          __may_alias__,
>                                          __aligned__ (1)));
> ```

(In case you were wondering, this is why dereferencing a `__m256*` is like `_mm256_store_ps`, not `storeu`.  `storeu` casts the pointer arg to the `_u` type defined with `aligned(1)`.)

GNU C native vectors without `may_alias` are allowed to alias their scalar type,  e.g. even without the `may_alias`, you could safely cast between `float*` and a hypothetical `v8sf` type.  But `may_alias` makes it safe to load from an array of `int[]`, `char[]`, or whatever.

---

### Other behaviour Intel's intrinsics require to be defined

Using Intel's API for `_mm_storeu_si128( (__m128i*)&arr[i], vec);` requires you to create potentially-unaligned pointers which would fault if you deferenced them.  And `_mm_storeu_ps` to a location that isn't 4-byte aligned requires creating an under-aligned `float*`.

**Just *creating* unaligned pointers, or pointers outside an object, is UB in ISO C++, even if you don't dereference them.**  I guess this allows implementations on exotic hardware which do some kinds of checks on pointers when creating them (possibly instead of when dereferencing), or maybe which can't store the low bits of pointers.  (I have no idea if any specific hardware exists where more efficient code is possible because of this UB.)

But implementations which support Intel's intrinsics must define the behaviour, at least for the `__m*` types and `float*`/`double*`.  This is trivial for compilers targeting any normal modern CPU, including x86 with a flat memory model (no segmentation); pointers in asm are just integers kept in the same registers as data.  (m68k has address vs. data registers, but it never faults from keeping bit-patterns that aren't valid addresses in A registers, as long as you don't deref them.)

---

### Going the other way: element access of a vector.

**Note that `may_alias`, like the `char*` aliasing rule, only goes one way**: it is *not* guaranteed to be safe to use `int32_t*` to read a `__m256`.  It might not even be safe to use `float*` to read a `__m256`.  Just like it's not safe to do `char buf[1024];`  `int *p = (int*)buf;`.

**See [GCC AVX __m256i cast to int array leads to wrong values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71364764) for a real-world example of GCC breaking code that points an `int*` into a `__m256i vec;` object.**  [Not a dereferenced `__m256i*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72382032/is-strict-aliasing-one-way) ; that would be safe if the only `__m256i` accesses were via `__m256i*`.  Because it's a `may_alias` type, the compiler can't infer that the underlying object is an `__m256i`; that's the whole point, and why it's safe to point it at an `int arr[]` or whatever.

GCC/clang define `__m128i` / `__m256i` as a vector of 2 or 4 `long long` elements, and `__m128` / `__m256` as a vector of 4 or 8 `float` elements, etc.  [GCC manual for Vector Extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html).  These might count as real `long long` or `float` objects you can safely point a `long long*` or `float*` at, but GCC doesn't explicitly document that even for its native vector types (but it does define `[]` indexing).  Even if they did, that would be an implementation detail for how GCC and Clang define Intel's vector types in terms of GNU or Clang vectors, not documented or guaranteed portable.  Except to MSVC which allow anything to alias anything, like `-fno-strict-aliasing`.   (And I think classic ICC was also like that, unlike LLVM-based ICX)

Reading/writing through a `char*` can alias anything, but when you have a `char` *object*, strict-aliasing does make it UB to read it through other types.  (I'm not sure if the major implementations on x86 do define that behaviour, but you don't need to rely on it because they optimize away `memcpy` of 4 bytes into an `int32_t`.  You can and should use `memcpy` to express an unaligned load from a `char[]` buffer, because auto-vectorization with a wider type is allowed to assume 2-byte alignment for `int16_t*`, and make code that fails if it's not: [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64))

A `char arr[]` may not be a great analogy because `arr[i]` is defined in terms of `*(arr+i)`, so there actually is a `char*` deref involved in accessing the array as `char` objects.  Perhaps some `char` members of a struct would be a better example, then.

---

To insert/extract vector elements, use shuffle intrinsics, SSE2 `_mm_insert_epi16` / `_mm_extract_epi16` or SSE4.1 insert / `_mm_extract_epi8/32/64`.  For float, there are no insert/extract intrinsics that you should use with scalar `float`.

Or store to an array and read the array.  ([print a __m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257166/print-a-m128i-variable/46752535#46752535)).  This does actually optimize away to vector extract instructions.

GNU C vector syntax provides the `[]` operator for vectors, like `__m256 v = ...;`  `v[3] = 1.25;`.  MSVC defines vector types as a union with a `.m128_f32[]` member for per-element access.

There are wrapper libraries like [Agner Fog's (now Apache-licensed) Vector Class Library](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) which provide portable `operator[]` overloads for their vector types, and operator `+` / `-` / `*` / `<<` and so on.  It's quite nice, especially for integer types where having different types for different element widths make `v1 + v2` work with the right size.  (GNU C native vector syntax does that for float/double vectors, and defines `__m128i` as a vector of signed int64_t, but MSVC doesn't provide operators on the base `__m128` types.)

---

You can also use union type-punning between a vector and an array of some type, which is safe in ISO C99, and in GNU C++, but not in ISO C++.  I think it's officially safe in MSVC, too, because I think the way they define `__m128` as a normal union.

There's no guarantee you'll get *efficient* code from any of these element-access methods, though.  Do not use inside inner loops, and have a look at the resulting asm if performance matters.

Comment: Curiously, while icc (unlike gcc and clang) is generally sophisticated enough to recognize that when a pointer which is converted from `T*` to `U*`, and used to access the storage before the next time it is accessed via other means, such an operation might actually affect the value of the `T` in question (i.e. it can handle type punning in cases *that don't actually involve aliasing*) my testing suggests that it does not handle such cases when they involve types `__m256*` and `uint32_t*`, even when the `uint32_t*` is derived from the same pointer object used to access the `__m256`.

Comment: You think this is a close enough of a dupe to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787268/how-to-implement-mm-storeu-epi64-without-aliasing-problems ? My vote is binding, so I'm hesitant to pull the trigger.

Comment: @Mysticial: hrm, yeah our answers could each almost answer both questions, even though the questions are slightly different (the other one seems to assume that `_mm_storeu_pd` will have the same aliasing semantics as a dereference, but it's an intrinsic so it could do anything.)  I like my answer better, because instead of saying there is (apparent) UB but it happens to work, I'm saying that compilers which support intrinsics *do* define the behaviour in this case.  That's my only hesitation in duphammering.  Maybe I should repost mine there?

Comment: Or close that as a dup of this?  But your answer is good, too.

Comment: @Mysticial I like your answer too, especially the trailing general guidelines.

Comment: I wonder whether declaring `implementation defined behavior` on the subject that is `undefined behavior` by the standard (e.g. __m256 allows aliasing) is always okey? For me even AVX512's `void*`, it looks somewhat "aliasing loophole" like the privileged one `memcpy` anyway.

Answer (score -4):

Note: This answer is valid for any ISO C++ standard from C++98 to the current draft.

It already starts out being Undefined Behavior on account of `__m256` not being a Standard type, nor a valid name for user-defined types. There's no good reason why the intrinsics library chose it; C++ added `namespace` explicitly to avoid clashes. `namespace avx { using m256 = ...` would make at least the name part well-defined.

Implementations can of course add specific additional guarantees, but *Undefined Behavior* means in relation to ISO C++.

Comment: Will you say `hwvec1` and `arr1` are implementation defined?

Comment: @sandthorn: That's another ISO C++ term, and no, ISO C++ says it's Undefined Behavior, not Implementation-Defined Behavior.

Comment: __m256 is provided by the implementation. It's an extension.

Comment: @MSalters Do `hwvec1` and `arr1` violate current strict aliasing rules?

Comment: @sandthorn: In an ISO C++ sense, the answer would be "Undefined Behavior already happened before (due to `__m256`), so further rules are meaningless. (You tagged it language-lawyer, so that's why I am lawyering. n.m. has a point that it's an extension, but one of the key reasons why Undefined Behavior exists in the standard is so that extensions are completely unrestricted in what they can achieve. )

Comment: Do you also imply that extensions are unrestricted even on strict aliasing rules?

Comment: @sandthorn: The problem from a Standard perspective is that it wants to allow extensions such as `extern "FORTRAN"` or `extern "JAVA"` or `__strict_aliasing(off)` or a million other things somebody may find useful. For those extensions to be useful, you expect a subset of C++ rules to hold, but the Standard simply cannot say in advance which rules still apply to which extension. That's why the language-lawyer answer is "`Undefined Behavior`, stop applying further rules"

Comment: @MSalters am downvoter. If you can show me the rule that says that using `__m256` type is *undefined* behaviour rather than *unspecified*, I'll remove the vote.

Comment: @user2079303 As you are here, Will you give some opinions about my question as another answer?

Comment: @user2079303: can you show the rule which says that it is *unspecified*?

Comment: @user2079303: See `[lex.name]` and also (by reference) C99 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers, which explicitly calls it Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @geza C++ standard doesn't specify `__m256`, thus there is no rule.

Comment: @MSalters being defined by the implementation, `__m256` is not only allowed, but in fact required to use a reserved name.

Comment: @user2079303: then why would it be unspecified behavior? Usually, the standard calls something else as "unspecified behavior". Like evaluation order for function call parameters, etc. Unspecified behavior is something, for which an implementation is not required to document the behavior. for `__m256`, an implementation surely can document the expected behavior.

Comment: @geza an implementation *may* document any unspecified behaviour. Implementation is *required* to document all implementation defined behaviour. Standard doesn't require implementations to specify the behaviour of `__m256`.

Comment: @user2079303: If an implementation gives a non-standard type, it definitely will document it. Otherwise it would be useless. For unspecified behaviors, compilers usually won't specify behavior, because it will depend on a lot of factors (optimization, etc.). So I don't think that `__m256` is unspecified behavior. Things that the standard doesn't specify is Undefined behavior: "behavior for which this document imposes no requirements". Just like `__m256`. The standard doesn't impose any requirement for this type.

Comment: @geza @user2079303  I never enrolled any law courses please correct me if I misunderstand anything. "`Unspecified behavior`" == "behavior not required by implementation document and standard document", "`Undefined behaviior`" == "behavior not required by the standard document". If those two statements earlier are true, so `undefined behaviors` is ***superset*** of `unspecified behaviors`.

Comment: @sandthorn: not exactly. As I understand, unspecified means that the compiler must choose from several possible behaviors, and it is unspecified, which is chosen. Undefined means **anything** can happen, the standard doesn't say what could happen. Unspecified and undefined behaviors are mutually exclusive (But maybe I'm wrong, I'm not a language lawyer either).

Comment: @geza: The Standard does not require that implementations be useful for any particular purpose, or any purpose whatsoever.  The question of what a quality implementation must do to be suitable for any purpose is largely orthogonal to the question of what an implementation must do to conform to the C Standard.

Comment: @geza: If an action invokes Undefined Behavior, that means that a compiler may behave in a fashion that would make it unsuitable for some purposes and yet still be conforming.  Some compiler writers seem to think that programmers have no right to expect anything of a compiler beyond the fact that it be "conforming" (e.g. expect that it be suitable for the purposes their programs are supposed to serve), and that any code which relies upon things beyond that is "broken".  Such a view is IMHO absurd, but seems to be steering current compiler philosophy.

Comment: @MSalters: I think the answer you posted is correct but not useful.  We want to know the semantics of `__m256*` *on implementations that do define it in the first place*, and which aim for compat with Intel's implementation / documentation.  Of course the ISO C++ standard has nothing to say about it.  I posted an answer that addresses it from that angle.

Comment: @supercat: I mostly agree with you. But what is the conclusion? :) I mean, is there something in my previous comments that you disagree with?

Comment: @geza: You seem to share the common presumption that compiler writers will try to make their compilers maximally suitable for the purposes to which their users would be likely to put them.  While I would say that would true of competent people seeking to write *quality* compilers, that is not true of all compiler writers/maintenance teams.

Comment: *C++ added namespace explicitly to avoid clashes* - Intel intrinsics work identically in C.  Using a namespace in the C++ version of their intrinsics would make their examples only work in one language or the other, not both.  (We both know that C and C++ are different languages, but Intel's intrinsics are clearly aimed at the compatible subset of those languages.  Or worse, at "C/C++" as a portable assembler. e.g. `_mm_loadu_si32` was only added within the past few years as a strict-aliasing-safe `movd` 32-bit load, previously IDK if `_mm_cvtsi32_si128( *(int*)ptr );` bare deref was intended.

Comment: Also note that Intel's intrinsics were originally (I think) implemented by Intel's own compiler, ICC.  So `__` names couldn't conflict with existing names in any codebases, and were part of Intel's C and C++ implementations.  (Later, other implementations like GCC and MSVC added support for the same intrinsics.)  Intel's documentation for them is still for the Intel compiler's implementation of them, and it's up to other implementations to follow that as a "standard".  They don't officially document the aliasing rules and so on, AFAIK, except by example.