# How to correctly use std::arch::_mm_loadu_si128 / _mm_storeu_si128

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior, simd, memory-alignment

Usually one should be wary of transmuting (or casting) pointers to a higher alignment. Yet the interface to the above functions require `*const _m128i` and `*mut _m128i` pointers, respectively. Both are SIMD-aligned, which means I'd need to keep my arrays SIMD-aligned, too. On the other hand, the intrinsics are explicitly designed to load/store *unaligned* data.

Is this safe? Shouldn't we change the interface? Or at least document this fact?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a cross-language duplicate of [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605).

As I explained over there, Intel defined the C/C++ intrinsics API such that `loadu` / `storeu` can safely dereference an under-aligned pointer, and that it's safe to create such pointers, even though it's UB in ISO C++ even to create under-aligned pointers.  (Thus implementations that provide the intrinsics API must define the behaviour).

The Rust version should work identically.  Implementations that provide it must make it safe to create under-aligned `__m128i*` pointers, as long as you don't dereference them "manually".

The other API-design option would be to have another version of the type that doesn't imply 16-byte alignment, like a `__m128i_u` or something.  GNU C does this with their native vector syntax, but that's way off topic for Rust.

Comment: "Thus implementations that provide the intrinsics API must define the behaviour" => can ? If ISO said UB it's UB, not implemented defined.

Comment: @Stargateur: If ISO C++ says "implementation defined", every implementation *must* define the behaviour (in one way or another).  If ISO C++ says something is UB, implementations *can* define the behaviour if they choose, and then code written to depend on such behaviour is no longer correct ISO C++.  e.g. `gcc -fwrapv` defines the behaviour of signed-integer overflow as 2's complement wraparound, like you get in assembly language.  But code that depends on `__m128i` being available in the first place can only work on the same limited set of implementations, so there's no downside.