# C++ SSE Intrinsics: Storing results in variables

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics

I have trouble understanding the usage of SSE intrinsics to store results of some SIMD calculation back into "normal variables". For example the _mm_store_ps intrinsic is described in the "Intel Intrinsics Guide" as follows:

> void _mm_store_ps (float* mem_addr, __m128 a)
>
> Store 128-bits (composed of 4 packed single-precision (32-bit)
>   floating-point elements) from a into memory. mem_addr must be aligned
>   on a 16-byte boundary or a general-protection exception may be
>   generated.

The first argument is a pointer to a float which has a size of 32bits. But the description states, that the intrinsic will copy 128 bits from a into the target mem_addr.

- Does mem_addr need to be an array of 4 floats?
- How can I access only a specific 32bit element in a and store it in a single float?
- What am I missing conceptually?
- Are there better options then the _mm_store_ps intrinsic?

Here is a simple struct where doSomething() adds 1 to x/y of the struct. Whats missing is the part on how to store the result back into x/y while only the higher 32bit wide elements 2 & 3 are used, while 1 & 0 are unused.

```
struct vec2 {
   union {
         struct {
            float data[2];
         };
         struct {
            float x, y;
         };
      };

   void doSomething() {
      __m128 v1 = _mm_setr_ps(x, y, 0, 0);
      __m128 v2 = _mm_setr_ps(1, 1, 0, 0);
      __m128 result = _mm_add_ps(v1, v2);
      // ?? How to store results in x,y ??
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `_mm_store_sd` to do a 64-bit store of the low half of a vector.  Or [`_mm_storel_pi`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVLPS.html) (`movlps`).  Instead of `_mm_setr`, you could use `_mm_load_sd((float*)&vec.x)` to do a 64-bit load that zero-extends to a 128-bit vector.

Comment: `mem_addr` doesn't need to be declared as a `float[]` but it needs to be properly aligned, which can be done with aligned allocation like `_mm_malloc` or `aligned_malloc`, although `malloc` should already allocate to `alignof(std::max_align_t)` bytes. If data is not dynamically allocated then `alignas` keyword should be used (on your `data` field of `vec2` type for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a 128-bit load or store, so yes the arg is like `float mem[4]`.  Remember that in C, passing an array to a function / intrinsic is the same as passing a pointer.

Intel's intrinsics are somewhat special because they don't follow the normal strict-aliasing rules, at least for integer.  (e.g. `_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)some_pointer)` doesn't violate strict-aliasing even if it's a pointer to `long`.  I think the same applies to the float/double load/store intrinsics, so you can safely use them to load/store from/to whatever you want.  Usually you'd use `_mm_load_ps` to load single-precision FP bit patterns, and usually you'd be keeping those in C objects of type `float`, though.

> How can I access only a specific 32bit element in a and store it in a single float?

Use a vector shuffle and then `_mm_cvtss_f32` to cast the vector to scalar.

---

### loading / storing 64 bits

Ideally you could operate on 2 vectors at once packed together, or an array of X values and an array of Y values, so with a pair of vectors you'd have the X and Y values for 4 pairs of XY coordinates.  (struct-of-arrays instead of array-of-structs).

But you *can* express what you're trying to do efficiently like this:

```
struct vec2 {
    float x,y;
};

void foo(const struct vec2 *in, struct vec2 *out) {
    __m128d tmp = _mm_load_sd( (const double*)in );  //64-bit zero-extending load with MOVSD
    __m128  inv = _mm_castpd_ps(tmp);             // keep the compiler happy
    __m128  result = _mm_add_ps(inv,  _mm_setr_ps(1, 1, 0, 0) );

    _mm_storel_pi( out, result );
}
```

[GCC 8.2 compiles it like this (on Godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0Astruct+vec2+%7B%0A++++float+x,y%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo(const+struct+vec2+*in,+struct+vec2+*out)+%7B%0A++++__m128d+tmp+%3D+_mm_load_sd(+(const+double*)in+)%3B++//64-bit+zero-extending+load+with+MOVSD%0A++++__m128++inv+%3D+_mm_castpd_ps(tmp)%3B+++++++++++++//+keep+the+compiler+happy%0A++++__m128++result+%3D+_mm_add_ps(inv,++_mm_setr_ps(1,+1,+0,+0)+)%3B%0A%0A++++_mm_storel_pi(+(__m64*)out,+result+)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.99203187250996,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:48.007968127490045,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.2',t:'0')),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:48.007968127490045,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), for x86-64 System V, strangely using `movq` instead of `movsd` for the load.  gcc 6.3 uses `movsd`.

```
foo(vec2 const*, vec2*):
        movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdi]           # 64-bit integer load
        addps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]     # packed 128-bit float add
        movlps  QWORD PTR [rsi], xmm0           # 64-bit store
        ret
```

For a 64-bit store of the low half of a vector (2 `float`s or 1 `double`), you can use `_mm_store_sd`.  Or better [`_mm_storel_pi`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVLPS.html) (`movlps`).  Unfortunately the intrinsic for it wants a `__m64*` arg instead of `float*`, but that's just a design quirk of Intel's intrinsics.  They often require type casting.

Notice that instead of `_mm_setr`, I used [`_mm_load_sd((const double*)&(in->x))`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSD.html) to do a 64-bit load that zero-extends to a 128-bit vector.  You don't want a `movlps` load because that merges into an existing vector.  That would create a false dependency on whatever value was there before, and costs an extra ALU uop.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and taking the time to do so. Did also not think of doing a shuffle before _mm_cvtss_f32.

Comment: Also note that a scalar float in asm is just a value in the bottom of an XMM register, unlike a scalar int which is normally in a GP-integer register.  So `_mm_cvtss_f32` is free, while `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` is normally a `movd eax, xmm0` (or directly to memory depending on what you do with the int.)

Comment: Also related: [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605) - even intrinsics like `_mm_load_sd(const double*)` are supposed to be strict-aliasing safe, i.e. you can use it to load two floats.  Last time I tested, it actually was safe in most compilers.