# How to best emulate the logical meaning of _mm_slli_si128 (128-bit bit-shift), not _mm_bslli_si128

Tags: c, sse, simd, intrinsics, sse2

Looking through the intel intrinsics guide, I saw this instruction. Looking through the naming pattern, the meaning should be clear: "Shift 128-bit register left by a fixed number of bits", but it is not. In actuality it shifts by a fixed number of *bytes*, which makes it exactly the same as `_mm_bslli_si128`.

- Is this an oversight? Shouldn't it be shifting by bits like `_mm_slli_epi32` or `_mm_slli_epi64`?
- If not, in which situation should I use this over `_mm_bslli_si128`?
- Is there an assembly instruction which does this correctly?
- What is the best way of emulating this with smaller shifts?

Comment: My comparison of older and newer documentaton *suggests* that the instruction `(V)PSLLDQ`, which shifts byte-wise, was first exposed via an inconsistently named intrinsic (using "slli", incorrectly suggesting bit shift), while the consistently named intrinsic (using "bslli", correctly suggesting byte shift) wasn't added until much later, at which point it was not possible to remove the old intrinsic without breaking existing code. For new code, use of the "bslli" variant therefore seems preferable as the more appropriately named intrinsics.

Comment: I sort of suspected it to be a historical artifact, but your comment confirms that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 that’s not an oversight. That instruction indeed shifts by bytes, i.e. multiples of 8 bits.

2 doesn’t matter, `_mm_slli_si128` and `_mm_bslli_si128` are equivalents, both compile into `pslldq` SSE2 instruction.

As for the emulation, I’d do it like that, assuming you have C++/17. If you’re writing C++/14, replace `if constexpr` with normal `if`, also add a message to the `static_assert`.

```
template<int i>
inline __m128i shiftLeftBits( __m128i vec )
{
    static_assert( i >= 0 && i < 128 );
    // Handle couple trivial cases
    if constexpr( 0 == i )
        return vec;
    if constexpr( 0 == ( i % 8 ) )
        return _mm_slli_si128( vec, i / 8 );

    if constexpr( i > 64 )
    {
        // Shifting by more than 8 bytes, the lowest half will be all zeros
        vec = _mm_slli_si128( vec, 8 );
        return _mm_slli_epi64( vec, i - 64 );
    }
    else
    {
        // Shifting by less than 8 bytes.
        // Need to propagate a few bits across 64-bit lanes.
        __m128i low = _mm_slli_si128( vec, 8 );
        __m128i high = _mm_slli_epi64( vec, i );
        low = _mm_srli_epi64( low, 64 - i );
        return _mm_or_si128( low, high );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `_mm_bslli_si128` - the newer name more clearly implies that it's a byte shift.  Note that you don't really need `if constexpr`.  That does maybe help your compiler make more efficient code in debug mode, if your compiler doesn't remove `if(false)` blocks in that case (*cough* MSVC), but that's all.  With `i` as a template parameter, it's definitely a compile-time constant and even MSVC does dead-code removal with optimization enabled.

Comment: @PeterCordes According to github.com, _mm_slli_si128 is ~13 times more popular, 109k versus 8k results. I’ve been writing SSE/AVX SIMD for years, yet before today I was never aware `_mm_bslli_si128` even exists.

Comment: @PeterCordes As for C++, the templates are required, IMO. The original C intrinsics are broken in that regard. Their prototype allows to pass non-constexpr values like a result of `rand()` which then fails to compile with a cryptic error like “expected constant expression”. If you write a function accepting `int` argument this may or may not happen depending if the function is inlined or not. Not the best UX. C++ templates with integer arguments and `if constexpr` handle that nicely, the language requires you to use a constexpr argument, and if you do so, the code is guaranteed to compile.

Comment: Yes, of course the templates are required so `i` can compile to an immediate.  That's what makes `if constexpr` *not* required.  `i` is still constant because you're not modifying *it* inside any of the branch bodies.

Comment: Also, it's unsurprising that existing codebases have much more use of the old less-clear `_mm_slli_si128` name than the newer clearer `_mm_bslli_si128` that's only been supported by compilers for the last ~5 years.  (Added at the same time as new intrinsics for AVX512 I think, see my answer when I post it.)  Intel introduced a new name so we can start using it because the old name sucked (IMO).

Comment: @PeterCordes Updated in case OP is using C++/14. I generally like compiler features which help me writing correct code; `if constexpr` is one of them, IMO — pass a non-constexpr and it won’t compile.

Comment: `i` is a template parameter.  You already can't do `shiftLeftBits<x>` for non-constant x.  Also, even if you put the code into a function with a plain `int` arg instead of a template, `_mm_slli_si128( vec, i / 8 );` will reliably fail to compile if constant-propagation can't make it into a compile-time constant.  (And some compilers won't handle  `_mm_slli_epi64( vec, i );` by compiling to `movd` / `psllq xmm, xmm`, but others surprisingly will.) Anyway, `if constexpr` isn't hurting readability much if any, if you're used to it, just wanted to note that it's not helping anything but MSVC debug

Comment: Posted an answer including which compiler versions support the newer `bslli` intrinsic.

Answer (score 4):

TL:DR: They're synonyms; the `bslli` name is newer, introduced around the same time as new AVX-512 intrinsics (sometime before 2015, *long* after SSE2 `_mm_slli_si128` was in widespread usage).  I find it clearer and would recommend it for new development.

---

SSE/AVX2/AVX-512 do not have bit-shifts with element sizes wider than 64.  (Or any other bit-granularity operation like `add`, except pure-vertical bitwise boolean stuff that's really 128 fully separate operations, not one big wide one.  Or for AVX-512 masking and broadcast-load purposes, can be in dword or qword chunks like `_mm512_xor_epi32` / [`vpxord`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pxor))

You have to emulate it somehow, which can be fairly efficient for compile-time-constant counts so you can pick between strategies according to `c >= 64`, with special cases for `c%8` reducing to a byte-shift.  Existing SO Q&As cover that, or see @Soonts' answer on this Q.

Runtime-variable counts would suck; you'd have to branch or do both ways and blend, unlike for element bit-shifts where `_mm_sll_epi64(v, _mm_cvtsi32_si128(i))` can compile to `movd` / `psllq xmm, xmm`.  Unfortunately, hardware variable-count versions of byte-shuffle/shift instructions don't exist, only for the bit-shift versions.

---

#### **`bslli` / `bsrli` are new, clearer intrinsic names for the same asm instructions**

The `b` names are supported in current version of all 4 major compilers for x86 ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJIDMpLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiggA6oFhdbT1DEzNLb181OjsHZyM3D05FZUxVfwYCZmICQONTC0SVCNo0jIIop1d3QQV0zOzgvOqSspi4rgBKRVQDYmQOAHIpc3tkQywAanFzHTwjI3sCYnsAOgRJ7HEABgBBAH0do05JAA48MZcFVgg9g%2BPTgDc28QB2WW2x97HiTAJu2jH9ow7c6sVh4Ha%2BQ5HCB3UhjSSPcyvLbPAAifQ6rBAfQArH1SKY%2Bhs8agsTo5HIxgouj1MBMLJw8QQsUS2h0ANYgbgbJaSABskk4Rw22KevIAnJxzNxsUIsdw8UYuBsNvjmcSsXiFCAVUzCejSHBYDAoMaIEg0EZPHh2GQKBALVabSBgNwjjKqNaCO4tRAXGrSC57BkAJ5YhmkC1GLQEADytFYob1pCwRhEwHY/vwXxSd0wWqTmAAHskDF6w3j5sp/aCXMQQ3osOXSAsZuWOjR6Ew2BwePxBMJRChyTIhHhzvAOqhPIV8wBaGPmTVJFIaCDWOqmBLWZoVeKkMJ%2BOgbrw%2BQ%2B0HexSoJJQFVI1LL6HJVZeFYqZC%2Bta/349fpr2cqXvEHRUt0vTtLKOJ4gSRKkCSfSFkcvKzry3BjMAyDIGM3BLEcSzYmMEC4IQJB0uYCRjHolrWu4pGcG0FHDtIjJqqypAIJgzBYB4EDsiA2IqpifTyqQircGKSzmE82JupI3CSkcQpimKqpJnBmras2LEGqa5qoFRNrkJQDrUR4IxppJhakB6rBesQPp%2Bkmga0CGTaRtGcYJpmmCpqIGZJlmyRqLm%2BYwUWJZln04aVoJME1nWxDBg2/Thi2iqRfqHaMCwGa9gIkhCGmQ4yHIo7jpAk7Tv4c4Lkut6ruuj7BFu2gfle%2B6noUP7teE/itXuN6BXeJRdQNK5FPefVVN%2BjWbooE3/i0V7AdSYF0RBuIqTBcEIUhKFjGZohjOYSxPARRFEMQtGwpRjo0YM8IMcVMjMXqrHsZxlQ8aQHL8RBwnQeqfTqTqLEYlikgKpyvJLBsvKw/DcOIxsTybYDL0stp8CGogKB6bdtpGXjJkgHgGGShsCTWbZ9n%2Bk5LnpRGelRvQHmJjBKZpn57N4NmQV5v6YXIKWyUVvQVZJnF9YYCLzaLGlDLtnQWXdlwvACJYA5iIxpVauVsGVXQ1WLvkg31doXXbgtu4nj1R4zTbZ6TdeL5DbU9vO3V41/tE1u/m7QSzY075W4B4EgTS4GCRtAOwViO3IahpOYZKMNLJwZ34BdV0UUTNqkeY9Fkk9TGaa9vG/YJwmKlKSxivxRyutKYpHGKTxPJYMdqYoGm6hj2Nmrj%2BnuIZ9q55UdzIJ4ng7HcnBijsPA7IWKFWZ63qUA5MF0wlrlM%2B58Zs3iHO%2Bf03O83gwUC8WQsRVFYsxXiksJUlTapW2VlK12OVq5yBWDhIxcdYTn1jOLE85JBjFnAAcTuLVU2pg1zm3dkcKwLUQ6tFCB1fwP4UEHkKJNSwo1XzTQDlwFBRDXalHQZUQhJCnyCjmt7ACGDlqgR7GDSCqNY7wT2kYBQE8xiz3EjwDOxFLqDHIjdEypFuCF0YujdEHR3pcUoOXAScooL%2Bi7lqEGZcIIQxEnxY6YpzAmLMaYixYpeCdw1KXFk5dxLtyeEcOe3ALAbEQtiGUgljY2KBnYxR%2BjIacGVFwruvdAm5jsv4TkQA%3D)), and I'd recommend them for new development unless you need backwards compat with crusty old compilers, or for some reason you *like* the old name that doesn't both to distinguish it from different operations.  (e.g. familiarity; if you don't want people to have to look up this newfangled name in the manual.)

- gcc since 4.8
- clang since 3.7
- ICC since ICC13 or earlier, Godbolt doesn't have any older
- MSVC since 19.14 or earlier, Godbolt doesn't have any older

---

If you check the intrinsics guide, [`_mm_slli_si128`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,Other&text=_mm_slli&expand=5322) is listed as an intrinsic for `PSLLDQ`, which is a byte shift.  This is not a bug, just Intel's idea of a joke, or whatever process they used to choose names for intrinsics back in the SSE2 days.  (There are only 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation and naming things).

Asm mnemonics also use the same pattern of not making the byte-shuffle one look different from the bit-shifts.  `psllw xmm, 1` / `pslld` / `psllq` / `pslldq`.  Again, you just have to know that 128-bit size is special, and must be a byte shuffle not a bit-shift, because x86 never has that.  (Or you have to check the manual.)

The asm manual entry for [`pslldq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pslldq) in turn lists intrinsics for forms of it, interestingly only using the `b` name for the `__m512i` AVX-512BW version.  When SSE2 and AVX2 were new, `_mm_slli_si128` and `_mm256_slli_si256` were the only names available, I think.  Certainly it post-dates SSE2 intrinsics.

(Note that the `si256` and `si512` versions are just 2 or 4 copies of the 16-byte operation, *not* shifting bytes across 128-bit lanes; something a few other Q&As have asked for.  This often makes AVX2 versions of shuffles like this and `palignr` a lot less useful than they'd otherwise be: either not worth using at all, or needing extra shuffles on top of it.)

**I think this new `bslli` name was introduced when AVX-512 was new**.  Intel invented some new names for other intrinsics around that time, and the AVX-512 load/store intrinsics take `void*` instead of `__m512i*`, which is a major improvement to amount of noise in code, especially for C where implicit conversion to `void*` is allowed.  (Creating a misaligned `__m512i*` [is not actually a problem in C terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond), but you couldn't deref it normally so it's a weird-looking thing to do.)  So there was cleanup work happening on intrinsic naming then, and I think this was part of it.

(AVX-512 also gave Intel the chance to introduce some fairly bad names, like `_mm_loadu_epi32(const void*)` - you'd guess that's a strict-aliasing-safe way to do a 32-bit `movd` load, right?  No, unfortunately, it's an intrinsic for `vmovdqu32 xmm, [mem]` with no masking.  It's just `_mm_loadu_si128` with a different C type for the pointer arg.  It's there for consistency with the naming pattern for `_mm_maskz_loadu_epi32`.  It would be nice to have `void*` load / store intrinsics for `__m128i` and `__m256i`, but if they have misleading names like that (esp. when you aren't using the `mask`/`maskz` versions in nearby code), I'll just stick to those cumbersome `_mm256_loadu_si256( (const __m256i*)(arr + i) )` casts for the old intrinsic, because I love typing `256` three times. >.<

I wish asm was more maintainable (or that intrinsics just used asm mnemonics) because it's much more concise; Intel generally does a good job naming their mnemonics.

---

It somewhat but not entirely helps to note the difference between `epi16/32/64` and `si128`: EPI = Extended (SSE instead of MMX) Packed Integer.  (Packed implying multiple SIMD elements).  `si128` means a whole 128-bit integer vector.

There's no way to infer from the name that you *aren't* just doing the same thing to a single 128-bit integer, instead of packed elements.  You just have to know that there are no bit-granularity things that ever cross 64-bit boundaries, only SIMD shuffles (which work in terms of bytes).  This avoids the combinatorial explosion of building a really wide barrel shifter, or of carry propagation at such a long distance for a 128-bit add, or whatever.