# Memory alignment of Armadillo vectors vec/fvec

Tags: c++, performance, intrinsics, armadillo

I want to load `__m256` directly from Armadillo vector data with `.memptr()`.
Does Armadillo ensure the data memory is 256-bits aligned? If it is then I would just convert the float/double pointer returned by `.memptr()` to `__m256` pointer and skip the `_mm256_load_ps()`, if it makes sense in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Armadillo do not seems to talk about this point in the documentation so it is left unspecified. Thus, vector data are likely not ensured to be 32-bytes aligned.

However, you do not need vector data to be aligned to load them in AVX registers: you can **use the unaligned load intrinsic `_mm256_loadu_ps`**. AFAIK, the performance of `_mm256_load_ps` and `_mm256_loadu_ps` is about the same on relatively-new x86 processors.

Comment: Thanks. I am curious what happens when I convert `float *` to `a __m256*` with `reinterpret_cast` then simply dereference the pointer, does the compiler automatically pick  `_mm256_loadu_ps`?

Comment: Using a `reinterpret_cast<Type>` on data not aligned with `sizeof(Type)` makes your program ill-formed in standard C++. Thus, loading 32-bytes unaligned data using such cast causes an undefined behaviour. Actually, I advise you not to use a `reinterpret_cast` even when data are aligned. You can find more information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605).

Comment: @Noob: `alignof(__m256) == 32`, so deref is equivalent to `load`, not `loadu`.  Fun fact: compilers like GNU C can implement `loadu` with a deref of an `__attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias,vector_size(32)))` type.  [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605).  For integer data you typically need some kind of cast (because Intel annoyingly defined the intrinsics to take `__m256i*` instead of `void*`), but yeah for float just use `_mm256_loadu_ps(const float*)`.

Comment: If your data happens to be 32-byte aligned at runtime, then great, otherwise the HW handles it; the penalty is non-existent if all 32 bytes come from the same cache line.  But cache-line splits have extra latency for OoO exec to hide and worse throughput from doing 2 cache accesses.  Page-splits are even worse especially on CPUs before Skylake, but of course happen rarely for sequential loops.