# Can't use uint64_t with rdrand as it expects unsigned long long, but uint64_t is defined as unsigned long

Tags: c++, long-integer, portability, intrinsics, rdrand

I've run into the following annoyance when trying to use rdrand intrinsic.

With my current compiler `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` are both 64-bits. However, uint64_t is defined as `unsigned long` while `_rdrand64_step` expects a pointer to `unsigned long long`.

On Intel's website the function is defined as `int _rdrand64_step (unsigned __int64* val)`. How can I handle this in a way that will be portable?

```
 #include <immintrin.h>
 #include <stdint.h>

 uint64_t example_rdrand64()
 {
     uint64_t n;
     _rdrand64_step(&n);
     return n;
 }
```

clang 11.0 `-march=ivybridge -O2` (https://godbolt.org/z/55sjsG):

```
error: no matching function for call to '_rdrand64_step'
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
from 'unsigned int *' to 'unsigned long long *' for 1st argument
_rdrand64_step(unsigned long long *__p)
```

Comment: What is wrong with using  `unsigned long long n;`?  Does that fail `_rdrand64_step (unsigned __int64* val)`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica my worry was that since Intel defines the intrinsic with `__int64`, there may be a compiler (or future compiler) that defines the intrinsic with `unsigned long` making this code break if I use `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `unsigned long long n;`**  You can still return it as a `uint64_t`.

It [works fine on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOQCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIRmzyAZ2ydURAg2rZ6mAMLp2AVwC29ELwCc5HZgAyBetgBypgEbZSIAKzkADuhKxJr0BsZmFtYBQRoMDk6uJh5evipqsfRMRKykRGGm5lbKqtjqIVk5RPEu7p4%2Bytm5%2BRFFSo1VjjVJdd4AlMroRqSoXADkMgDMjqjGOADUkhN6BCYmjkSkjgB0SIu4kgAMAIKT07PYC0tthIw7e4dHRusAbLwA%2BkRz2AAerCZ%2BnDepEwpDEmFeEF6D0kAHZ5Mc5oi5kZ6EFgE5MHN2AxgFicXN6ItZEiAPQkuYAdzIAGslF8AG6eACeFKQnmwWweSLmZORqII6OwmLebxevAJRMRvIAkno9HMwXMALJMABq8oY7CZXKRQJBYNebza2D8EBkz3oUIm8KO3NI2CIQ3oEut0JhABEHqN%2BuwQKNvKNyOZRgdA%2Bg/XoFAo5kpBsMLpNuIGiH7Q71%2BtSfAcRH7eIGTFmg6mw37A0oQNmUyHveQ4LAUBh/gROBQqBBG35m3VgNwDtJyDRm0RPOWIG5i%2BQ3I4cky/UnyI2TDoiAB5ehaic4ExiYCcTcEe1lRnl6s2b6lIzDueB9aqCfsAhuUGkJkGHATjYra/9OiMFgcLg%2BEEEAJhEHc0CjOQREfctIH6dA/AyE8AFpt2GXYJndAh6SZJ8CEwYALmQldpDmZCAHUOHYMsSjKLQIFsZpzG4GxdGqRJkmEaJggYJiuMCHj6HY2ovBYtJSgyComkMAphHEujMnaYTulEhpKj4sSlM6Di6m4fpYyGEYeB9P0AyLU9w1Gb4AA5nmQ145mAVBUDmXstlIiB8GIMgFmkCYWLmAwmxbXyJgmXpAsg2Rk2LdNyDZVgcC8SEc1GPNyALbxs2DUNyEsssK3IKs0wzQtfVGCZAxyktRhi6t%2BjrBB4AgBt0GCzxKGoDsuy8GYd24XsWMHdhh1IUdx1PKd6Bna8FzapdGDXDdTy3Hc9xWg8JOw7AT1yn4LyvUZ51vcrcofJ8ZzfMZcs/AsjprX9mDYPcgKEftRHECC5AUaC3FglKEKQv1UJyVAMKwnC8IIoiSMRCiqJo9IQm0XQNNY%2BxtJE/iYhCNHuIyZTOLE2jJPaNH5NJypCd0tTpPCZjaY6BIsb0gZDMAkz/SqidLJsuyHL68RXO4LYDi2bg5k8wgSFIUKAqCzsQsmaQIsjb65DqkryEzLLUvSgswq2MLjZN03nnM3L8uUQriprRqWrQNrFY6ttupbEACGc6Q%2BwG/thtG8aJymmb7rm1ZlyW2cVuwbdxHW3LCEPDRjwnfbUEvMZjsYO9T3O59Xywa7k02O6kx/BgnoAnh%2BCEFiPokKLfv%2B%2BDEJCFC0LBxYIdwzZobI2H4fYajiiR%2BjGJkiIWNsanVPx3GJ4Zue4kxlS5JJ8oyYXtfR8UqmV6Jxnya05nV9Zgz42M1KzOqvK/T5%2BzxU9lzvekEWRY8ryZbl8hAqdnq5dVlFTW3pOb6xAhMI2psoFhXNjfK25ZKyxVrIgB2bsXZdT/u7UY9JUB%2BD8G8ek3BLBvGkNZN4EBVRMG4M8N4lhehvG%2BK8QM/sRzUAmrlYOL5ZqLgjuuKOCcY5rSLuQROW0U6njThnWaJ17yPnzldD8JdvwDgrv%2BF6NcLBgU%2BlIdWihzrNzyq3BgKESKIy2mPVGW8p5sX3jTJeoQrH%2BAEgTWxqkKYb3Uo49xDApJMy6AfNonj6ZyWPv43S%2Bk4xGVZuVa%2BPM74ORMEoHBcxCGWHctZSWlDqFbDoZLT%2BPlEw/wVv/SYvBAG6OAXFcqYDDbQOgRbGqBVEH1VKrrcqlUGm31qkVWKnNpDcwsqWHpLTyCMjGsjXgQA) with current versions of all 4 major x86 compilers (GCC, clang, ICC, MSVC).  Note that `_rdrand64_step` will only ever work on x86-64 C++ implementations, so that limits the scope of portability concerns a *lot*.

**All 4 mainstream x86 compilers define `_rdrand64_step` with a type compatible with `unsigned long long`, so in this case it's safe to just follow clang's headers.**

Unfortunately (or not), gcc/clang's immintrin.h doesn't actually define a `__int64` type to match Intel's intrinsics documentation, otherwise you could use that.  ICC and MSVC do let you actually use `unsigned __int64 n`.  (https://godbolt.org/z/v4xnc5)

---

`immintrin.h` being available at all implies [a *lot* of other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond) about the compiler environment and type widths, and it's highly unlikely (but not impossible) that some future x86-64 C implementation would make `unsigned long long` anything other than a qword (uint64_t).

Although if they did, maybe they'd just map Intel's `__int64` to a different type, since Intel's docs never use `long` or `long long`, just `__int64`, e.g. AVX2 `_mm256_maskload_epi64(__int64 const* mem_addr, __m256i mask)`.  (Or even `__m128i*` for the `movq` load intrinsic:
`__m128i _mm_loadl_epi64 (__m128i const* mem_addr)`.
Much later, a more sane `__m128i _mm_loadu_si64 (void const* mem_addr)` was introduced (along with AVX512 intrinsics.)

But still, a C++ implementation with an `unsigned long long` that wasn't exactly 64 bits would probably break some intrinsics code, so it's not a problem you need to spend any time really worrying about.  In *this* instance, if it were wider, that would still be fine.  You'd just be returning the low 64 bits of it, where `_rdrand64_step(&n);` put the result.  (Or you'd get a compile error if that C++ implementation had the intrinsic take `unsigned long` or however they define `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned long long`).

**So there's zero chance of silent data corruption / truncation on any hypothetical future C++ implementation.**  ISO C++ guarantees that **`unsigned long long` is *at least* a 64-bit type**.  (Actually specifies it by value-range, and being unsigned that its value bits are plain binary, but same difference.)

You don't need portability to a DeathStation 9000, just to any hypothetical future compiler that anyone might actually want to use, which pretty much implies that it would want to be compatible with existing Intel-intrinsics codebases, if it provides that style of intrinsics at all.  (Rather than a redesign from scratch with different names and types, in which case you'd have to change 2 lines in this function to get it to work.)

Comment: Whatever the intrinsics are doing, the _rdrand_step and related functions ultimately derive from the library I wrote to first excercise the RdRand instruction on the first test silicon. The current version of that library uses stdint and is here: https://github.com/dj-on-github/rdrand_stdint . You may find the functions familiar and I find that they are less bother than the intrinsics.

Comment: @DavidJohnston: `int _rdrand64_step (unsigned __int64* val)` is an intrinsic for the [`rdrand` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdrand) with 64-bit operand-size.  (The asm manual entry for it does list `_rdrand64_step` ).  It should always expand to exactly one `rdrand` instruction, with the CF result as the return value and the output register as the by-reference operand.  I assume the intrinsic name includes "step" to remind users that they need to check the bool-as-int return value in a do{}while() or similar.  (Presumably that was your idea and they used names from your lib.)

Comment: Being intrinsics, the compiler can branch on the CF result directly instead of materializing it as an actual `int` in a GP-integer register the way your library does with inline-asm.  Thanks for linking your library, though, useful for the retry functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the designer of the RNG behind RdRand and RdSeed. I use my own library, not intrinsics since they always give me problems. The library is here : https://github.com/dj-on-github/rdrand_stdint