# VLD2 structure load of a stricter alignment type

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics, memory-alignment, neon

Can a byte pointer ever be safely passed to `vld2q_u16`?
I'm mostly concerned about static analyzer complaints.

```
uint16x8x2_t load_interleaved_shorts (const uint8_t* const ptr) {
    uint16_t* p16 = (uint16_t*)ptr; // possible undefined behavior ?
    return vld2q_u16(p16);
}
```

In my instance:
The pointer is always aligned to a 16 byte boundary.
The compiler doesn't known the alignment of the pointer.
The code must be portable and strictly follow the C90 standard.

Assumptions:
Replacing `vld2q_u16` with `vld1q_u8 / vuzpq_u8` would hurt performance.
The probability of the compiler optimizing a scalar pattern into a `vld2q_u16` is small.

Edit: suppressed some warnings by casting to a void pointer.
`vld2q_u16((const uint16_t*)(const void*)src)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code must be portable and strictly follow the C90 standard.

... plus everything implied by the presence of ARM NEON intrinsics! (Although that may not help a static analyzer).  (Related: [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond) discusses that for x86, but your case is a bit different; your pointers are aligned).

---

In C, it's safe to cast between pointer types (without dereferencing) as long as you never create a pointer with insufficient alignment for its type.  You don't need a compile-time-visible guarantee of alignment, you just need to not ever actually create a `uint16_t*` that doesn't have `alignof(uint16_t)` alignment.

(This makes it unlikely for a static analyzer to complain even if that wasn't the case, unless it could see something like `(uint16_t*)(1 + (char*)&something_aligned)` where you take an aligned address and offset it by an odd number, which would be guaranteed to produce a misaligned address.)

And in practice, compilers targeting byte-addressable machines do more or less define the behaviour even for creating misaligned pointers. (For example, Intel intrinsics for unaligned loads depend on creating an unaligned `__m128i*`.)  As long as you don't deref them, which is unsafe even in practice on targets that allow unaligned loads; see [my answer on this Q&A for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64) and the blog links that cover other examples.

**So you're 100% fine**: your code never creates a misaligned `uint16_t*`, and doesn't directly dereference it.

If ARM has unaligned-load intrinsics, it would even be safe to form a misaligned `uint16_t*` and pass it to the function; the existence/design of the intrinsics API implies that it's safe to use it that way.

---

Other things that are undefined behaviour but which you aren't doing:

- It's technically UB to form a pointer that isn't pointing inside an object, or one-past-end, but in practice mainstream implementations allow that as well.
- It's strict-aliasing UB to dereference a `uint16_t*` that doesn't point to `uint16_t` objects.  But any dereferencing only happens inside intrinsic "functions", so you don't have to worry about the strict-aliasing rule.  (Which may pointer-cast to some special type and deref, or may pass the pointer on to a `__builtin_arm_whatever()` compiler built-in.)

**I assume that ARM load/store intrinsics are defined similar to `memcpy`, being able to read/write the bytes of any object.**  So e.g. you could `vld2q_u16` on an array of `int`, `double`, or `char`.  Intel intrinsics *are* defined that way (e.g. GCC/clang use `__attribute__((may_alias))`.)  If not, it wouldn't be safe.

And BTW, the `char*`-can-alias-anything rule only works one way.  Yes it's safe to point a `char*` at a `uint16_t`, but if you have an actual *array* of `char buf[100]`, those objects are definitely char objects, and it's UB to access them through a `uint16_t*`.  However, if you only have `char*`, and only one other pointer-type other than `char*` is used, then you can look at the memory as having whatever the other type is, and every `char*` access aliasing that.

Comment: gcc casts to `__builtin_neon_hi *` but I can't find info on that type.

Comment: @aqrit: GCC integer type size codes are "si" = single integer (i.e. `int`), "hi" = half-integer, "di" = double-integer, etc.  So I assume it's a builtin name for a NEON vector of half-int (int16_t) elements.  IDK where to find more general details on `__builtin_neon_*`, but a google search found GCC source code saying those names are *not* user-visible.  https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/15d30d2f20794d29ceabcfd57d230d6387284115/gcc/config/arm/arm-builtins.c#L1360.

Comment: You can construct test cases to see whether they respect aliasing, e.g. store a uint16, vector load, store another uint16, and vector load again.  If the optimize doesn't realize that the vector load aliases the uint16_t assignment, it can eliminate the first one as a "dead store".

Comment: Lost cause, just got `error: cast from 'const BYTE *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') to 'const __m128i *' increases required alignment from 1 to 16 [-Werror,-Wcast-align]`

Comment: @aqrit: ah, yes, static analysis will sometimes warn about things that *can* be part of legal code, but can also be signs of problems.  Sounds like you should just use `-Wno-cast-align`, or enable that via pragma for some functions.  Don't make your code worse just to keep an over-cautious compiler warning happy.  (Or possibly you can use `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` on the pointer type?  But that can easily get you into a mess where *each* `aligned_char` element has size 16, including padding, instead of just promising the compiler that one specific pointer is aligned.)