# AVX-512: _mm512_load vs. standard pointer casting?

Tags: c, intrinsics, avx512

In my testing the following code seems to execute fine:

```
double* ptr = _aligned_malloc(sizeof(double) * 8, 64);
__m512d* vect = (__m512d*)ptr;
```

However, AVX provides functions to do the exact same thing - `_mm512_load_pd`. Is the code above considered dangerous in any way? I am assuming the only difference between the standard pointer casting and the intrinsic is that the intrinsic will immediately load the data onto a 64 byte register while the pointer casting will wait for a further instruction to do so. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am assuming the only difference between the standard pointer casting and the intrinsic is that the intrinsic will immediately load the data onto a 64 byte register while the pointer casting will wait for a further instruction to do so.

Nope, not at all.  They're exactly identical, no diff in generated asm.  On most compilers, `_mm512_load_pd` is just a plain inline function that does something like `return *(__m512d *) __P;` - that's an exact copy-paste from GCC's headers.  So a load intrinsic is literally already doing this.

`__m512d` is not fundamentally different from `double` or `int` in terms of how the compiler does register allocation, and decides when to actually load C objects that happen to be in memory.  The compiler can fold a load into a later ALU instruction (or optimize it away) regardless of how you write it.  (And with AVX-512, may be able to fold `_mm512_set1_pd(x)` broadcast-loads for instructions with a matching element width.)

The `_mm*_load[u]_*` intrinsics may *look* like you're asking for a separate load instruction at that point, but that's not really what happens.  That just makes your C look more like asm if you want it to.

Just like `memcpy` between two `int` objects can be optimized away or done when it's convenient (as long as the result is as-if it were done in source order), so can store/load intrinsics depending on how you use them.  And just like a `+` operator doesn't have to compile to an `add` instruction, `_mm_add_ps` doesn't necessarily have to compile to `addps` with those exact operands, or to addps at all.

Load/store intrinsics basically exist to communicate alignment guarantees to the compiler (via loadu/storeu), and to take care of types for you (at least for ps and pd load[u]/store[u];  integer still requires casting the pointer).  Also for AVX-512, to allow masked loads and masked stores.

> Is the code above considered dangerous in any way?

No.  Plain dereference is still strict-aliasing safe because `__mm*` types are special.  See
[Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond)