# Why does Clang complain about alignment on SSE intrinsic unaligned loads

Tags: clang, sse, intrinsics, memory-alignment

When compiling the FLAC project with GCC, I get (almost) no compiler warnings. However, on compiling with clang, I get *a lot* of warnings like these

```
 lpc_intrin_sse2.c:85:49: warning: cast from 'const FLAC__int32 *' (aka 'const int *') to 'const __m128i *' increases required alignment from 4 to 16 [-Wcast-align]
                                                mull = _mm_madd_epi16(q9, _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(data+i-10))); summ = _mm_add_epi32(summ, mull);
                                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't really understand why. The instruction used here is *specifically* one to accept unaligned loads (hence the loadu), and gcc doesn't seem to mind. I know aligned loads are better/faster, but the code doesn't really permit that here, as each instruction accesses the data 4 bytes further. Getting this aligned would require copying the data 4 times with different alignments, which will probably cause cache problems.

Am I right in judging that there is indeed no problem? If there indeed is no problem, what is the best way to silence this warning? Is replacing `(const __m128i*)` with `(const __m128i*)(const void*)` acceptable here?

Comment: Can you cast to `__m128i_u const *` instead? (If that breaks portability, make some `#if`-guarded typedef)

Comment: Would that be better than casting `(const __m128i*)(const void*)`? That seems more portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alignof(__m128i) == 16`.  That cast happens *before* the `__m128i*` is passed as an argument to `_mm_loadu_si128`, which casts it again, not actually dereferencing the `__m128i*`.

As @chtz points out, you could maybe work around this for clang by casting instead to `__m128i_u const *`.  GCC/clang define those types with `__attribute__((may_alias,aligned(1),vector_size(16)))`, unlike the standard `__m128i` type which doesn't override the alignment-requirement.  But I don't think MSVC defines a `__m128i_u`, so that wouldn't be portable.

---

**You're right there is no actual problem, just an artifact of Intel's poor design for their intrinsics API** where even the unaligned-load intrinsics take a pointer that wouldn't be safe to dereference on its own.  (For AVX-512, the new intrinsics take `void*` instead, also avoiding the need for stupid casting, but they didn't retroactively change the old intrinsics to take `void*`.)

If clang's warning checker followed the chain of usages of that pointer value, it would see that it's not dereferenced.  But it doesn't do that, instead it warns you on the spot about having created a pointer that might not be safe to deref.  That's normally not something you want to do, but as I said you're forced to do it by Intel's clunky API.

Related: [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond) discusses the behaviour that compilers must define as part of supporting the intrinsics API, including creating misaligned pointers.  It's ISO C UB to simple create a misaligned `int *` even without dereferencing, but obviously the intrinsics API requires you to create misaligned `__m128i*` pointers to use `loadu` / `storeu`.  (And potentially misaligned `float*` to use `_mm_loadu_ps` on bytes that weren't a valid aligned `float` object, but the intrinsic doesn't deref the `float*`, instead it casts to `__m128_u*`)