# What is the proper method to load GNU C generic vectors?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, webassembly, simd

GCC/Clang provided vector extensions are a convenient way to enable SIMD vectorisation on multiple architectures (like webassembly, arm64, x64).

With

```
using v8x16u = uint8_t __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
v8x16u add(v8x16u a, v8x16u b) { return a + b; }
        add     v0.16b, v1.16b, v0.16b
        ret
```

it easy to do some SIMD programming (even if not too highly performant on some cases).

What I've not been able to find from any documentation is ***what is the preferred/canonical way to initialise these vectors from memory***.

```
v8x16u load(uint8_t const *p) {
   v8x16u a;
   for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) a[i] = p[i];
}
```

does work as expected on clang x64, clang armv8 and little bit unoptimally with GCC 7.3

```
   ldr q0, [x0]    // clang armv8
   movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]  // gcc x64 7.3
   movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi]  // clang 15.0.0 x64

   sub     sp, sp, #16 // GCC arm64 7.3
   ldr     q0, [x0]
   add     sp, sp, 16
```

In webassembly the result is a disaster (a loop).
Unrolling the load works for webassembly and clang, but not for GCC, which does 16 individual byte loads

```
v8x16u load(uint8_t const *p) {
   v8x16u a{p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],
            p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7],
            p[8],p[9],p[10],p[11],
            p[12],p[13],p[14],p[15]
   };
   return a;
}
        local.get       0
        v128.load       0:p2align=0
        end_function
```

Finally type punning does compile, but wouldn't it introduce UB -- and also it seems that clang might have a bug in the implementation (as using vs typedef should AFAIK work equally in this case, preserving the attributes)

```
v8x16u load_fail(uint8_t const *p) {
    using Vec = uint8_t __attribute__((vector_size(16), aligned(1)));
    return *reinterpret_cast<const Vec*>(p);
}
        movaps  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi]

v8x16u load_okish(uint8_t const *p) {
    typedef uint8_t Vec __attribute__((vector_size(16)))  __attribute__((aligned(1)));
    return *reinterpret_cast<const Vec*>(p);
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi]
}
```

Comment: IIRC, it's supposed to be safe (even with strict aliasing) to point a pointer-to-GCC vector of `float` at  an array of `float` and dereference it, for example.  [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605) explains that deref of `__m256*` is safe, but that's true no matter what it's pointing to because it uses `__attribute__((may_alias))`.

Comment: I'd have expected `load_fail` to work.  Smells like a clang bug, although 
 https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/xmmintrin_8h_source.html#l01744 shows clang using a seemingly over-complicated deref of a struct-pointer to a struct containing a `__m128_u` (like `__m128` but with aligned(1)).  I wonder if that's an intentional workaround?  https://godbolt.org/z/5Tnn66ooK

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html shows an example of using `memcpy` to load a vector.  Err actually that's to load a *union* of your own native-vector type (with a desired element size) and `__m128i` from immintrin.h so you can easily use intrinsics on it.  (If you want to mix intrinsics + convenient operators on vectors with a useful element-size, normally use Agner Fog's vectorclass library if using x86.)  Anyway, maybe try `memcpy`, but that would also be defeat type-based alias analysis because memcpy is unaligned and can alias anything.

Comment: Huh, https://godbolt.org/z/ecYa6rEE5 shows clang is broken with memcpy as well, emitting an alignment-required `movaps`.

Comment: I do not want to use any third-party libraries (Agner Fog) due to licensing or attribution issues; also I wan't to use the vector extensions as the base class in order of having 95% of all algorithms work without HW specific headers (xmmintrin.h, arm_neon.h or wasm_simd128.h) -- cross platform. One aspect is also the compilation speed (where the intrinsic headers would possibly cost minutes more).

Comment: Added a clang issue: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/68560

Comment: Right, Agner Fog's VCL wouldn't even fit your use-case anyway since it's x86-specific.  (It is Apache licensed now, though, not GPL).  I mentioned it as an alternative to the use-case the GCC manual was discussing in the memcpy example, because I can't resist going off on a tangent :P  Yeah, pure `__attribute__((vector_size(16)))` is good for basic cases of manual vectorization, combined with the few `__builtin` functions GCC supports for some shuffling.

Comment: @PeterCordes re "clang is broken with memcpy", that's because you have `v8x16u *` in the prototype, and LLVM, unlike GCC, appears to derive guaranteed alignment from a declaration or a cast: https://godbolt.org/z/xjoxPKqcT

Comment: @amonakov: huh.  So maybe the weird implementation (with a struct) of clang's `_mm_loadu_si128` is to defeat that inference, since the poor design of Intel's intrinsics API requires that function to take a potentially-misaligned `__m128i *`.  (Thus implicitly requiring implementations to define the behaviour of creating a misaligned pointer, which is UB in ISO C even without dereferencing it.)  But I guess clang doesn't in general define that behaviour, only for Intel intrinsics, and does normally assume that a pointer is at least as aligned as any type you cast it to.

Comment: @PeterCordes it appears to be limited to types of memcpy arguments, not all casts in general. Passing `(void*)(int*)x` as argument to memcpy does not imply any alignment for `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast a pointer to the vector type with the appropriate `aligned` attribute, and dereference it. It does not introduce UB when the type of pointed-to memory (its dynamic type, which may be different from declared type — after placement new, or if it is allocated on the heap in the first place) is compatible with the underlying scalar type of the vector. GCC allows aliasing between scalar and vector types, but does not document it yet. For Clang/LLVM it appears to be the same (allows aliasing without documenting). For both compilers the guarantee naturally falls out of how autovectorization internally introduces vector-typed accesses to arrays of scalars.

Due to the Clang bug noted in the comments, the variant with reduced alignment needs to be introduced with `typedef` rather than `using`.

You may additionally introduce vector variants with the `may_alias` attribute for use when accessing memory with unknown/arbitrary type (when the scalar implementation would use `memcpy` or char-based accesses), or use a vector of `char` to perform the memory access, then bit-cast the vector to the type needed for computations.

Using `memcpy` is risky because system headers commonly override it with an inline variant using `__builtin_object_size` for hardening (the so-called `FORTIFY_SOURCE` feature), which interferes with optimization, particularly speed/size estimates for inlining. It's possible to avoid that using `__builtin_memcpy` explicitly, but at that point using custom vector types seems cleaner.