# What is the correct way to mix clang vector extensions with normal data

Tags: c++, performance, clang, undefined-behavior, simd

Recently I learned that a lot of tricks I learned are considered undefined behavior... and I have a feeling that compilers are getting more and more sensitive about undefined behavior.

So I was wondering what is the correct way to speed up (for example) data processing with clang/gcc vector extensions? More exactly:

- given e.g. the type alias `typedef float float4 __attribute__((vector_size(16)));`
- given e.g. two buffers containing floating point data (e.g. `std::vector<float>` or `float[]`)

How to properly process them? For example I would have done this way:

```
typedef float float4 __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

float sum_of(const float* data, int n) {
    // For simplicity let's assume n is a multiple of 4
    float4 sum{0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f};
    const float4* ptr = (const float4*)data;
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 4; i++) sum += *ptr++;
    return sum[0] + sum[1] + sum[2] + sum[3];
}
```

When I test it, it seems to work, but I have a feeling that casting float* to float4* is undefined behavior. So what would be the correct (and still fast) way to do it?

Note: I'm interested in C++11 and/or c++17 (for practical reasons, the latest C++ compiler is not always available on every platform we need to target)

(Note: I know that in c++ I'm not supposed to use C style cast, but IMHO that is irrelevant to the current topic)

Comment: *"I have a feeling that casting float\* to float4\* is undefined behavior"* Theoretically, this is UB indeed in C++ due to the strict aliasing rule. However, in practice, you are using a compiler extension so I think this is the same issue that casting a `float*` to a `__m128*` (implementation defined). The alignment of the `float4` is pretty important, especially if `alignof(float4) > alignof(float)`. In this case, you need to compute the first items that are not aligned, then compute the main loop, then the remaining items. AFAIK, some SIMD instruction sets require data to be aligned.

Comment: If you want to be completely safe, you can do a `memcpy` so to avoid breaking the strict aliasing rule. Most compiler can optimize it out so there should be a very small or even no overhead (possibly a register copy which is very cheap but not free), especially with Clang/GCC.

Comment: By the way, `ext_vector_type(4)` does not seem supported by GCC, only Clang. However, `vector_size(4)` seems supported by both. Also note that there is a table describing the support of casts in multiple platform in the [Clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) but it is not clear whether it includes pointer-based casts or not.

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error, I indeed wanted to write the example with `vector_size` (though I think it should be `vector_size(16)` since it's the size in bytes)

Comment: N.B.: In your loop you need `*ptr++` instead of `*data++` -- otherwise it will broadcast and add every `data[]` value to all entries of `sum` (make sure to actually test your code and have a look at the generated assembly). And for the final sum `(sum[0]+sum[2]) + (sum[1]+sum[3])` would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Sorry... I missed that as well... will edit the post

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Not quite the same as `__m128*`.  `__m128` is defined with `__attribute__((may_alias))` so it can point at *anything*, the way `char*` can.  `float4*` can only point at aligned floats.  (But the GCC manual doesn't actually say that! https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html .  It doesn't show any loading or storing examples, either.  So that's very bad and needs documenting; I don't think it's intentionally undocumented = not guaranteed or else they'd probably warn against it.  I'm confident it is actually safe and well-defined by GCC and Clang)

Comment: For `__m128*`, see [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605).  And BTW, yes, without `__attribute__((aligned(4)))` or `aligned(1)`, `alignof(float4)` is `16`, so this function tells the compiler you're doing aligned loads, and for example can use x86 legacy-SSE `addps xmm0, [rdi]` instead of needing a separate `movups` load.  (AVX memory source operands don't need to be aligned, SSE do.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Good to know. I missed that. So adding `__attribute__((may_alias))` to the typedef of the OP should be enough here, isn't it? (assuming both are supported together, but I expect the compiler to report an error if this is not the case). The side effect is that the compiler may generate a less efficient code due to the possible aliasing...

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Yes, you can combine all the attributes I mentioned into one `__attribute__((aligned(1), may_alias))` typedef; that's how GCC implements `_mm_loadu_ps`.  But you don't *need* `may_alias` at all to point a `float4*` at `float` data, as long as it's aligned by 16.  Hopefully that's documented somewhere, but I'm at least 99% sure that's true, unlike if you were pointing it at a `char []` buffer or something where that would violate strict-aliasing (again, same as a `float*`.)  The vector's element type is `float`, and I think it works something like an array of `float`.

Comment: The `for` line shouldnt be `for (int i = 0; i < (n + 3) / 4; i++) sum += *ptr++;` ?