# simd find first element greater than x

Tags: c++, simd, avx512

I'm learning to use SIMD in c++, and this is my attempt at implementing a SIMD version of "find the first element greater or equal to X".

My questions:

- Can the `reinterpret_cast` be replaced with some intrinsic?
- Is it better to make sure the content `reinterpret_cast` is aligned, by starting in a similar way to the end, and using non-simd logic for elements upto the first aligned short?

```cpp
// reference function of desired behavior
inline auto find_first_greater_or_equal_simple(const std::vector<short>& v, short insert)
{
    for (auto it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (*it >= insert) return it;
    }
    return v.end();
}

// simd version
inline auto find_first_greater_or_equal_simd(const std::vector<short>& v, short insert)
{
    const __m512i target = _mm512_set1_epi16(insert);

    auto it = v.begin();
    const auto end = v.end();
    const auto end_simd = it + 32 * ((end - it) / 32);

    __mmask32 cmpge_mask{};

    for (; it != end_simd &&
        !(cmpge_mask = _mm512_cmpge_epi16_mask(*reinterpret_cast<const __m512i*>(&*it), target));
        it += 32)
    {}

    if (cmpge_mask)
    {
        unsigned long local_idx;
        _BitScanForward(&local_idx, cmpge_mask); // todo: __builtin_ctz 
        return it + local_idx;
    }

    for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (*it >= insert) return it;
    }

    return v.end();
}
```

Comment: Given AVX-512, you definitely have BMI2 for `_tzcnt_u32`, so use that instead of compiler-specific intrinsics for BSF.  Or use C++20 `std::countr_zero`

Comment: @PeterCordes The compiler is free to generate `tzcnt` for `_BitScanForward`, if the target CPU permits (and it does, when AVX-512 is enabled). gcc does just that for `__builtin_ctz`, for example.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: No, `_BitScanForward` is an intrinsic for `bsf` specifically (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsf).  As usual, MSVC takes it literally, not using `tzcnt` with `-arch:AVX2` or `-arch:AVX512`  https://godbolt.org/z/K9T8Tc9rb  (MSVC's -arch:AVX2 *does* imply BMI1+2, as you can see from it using tzcnt for `std::countr_zero`.  MSVC treats "AVX2" the way GCC/Clang treat `-march=x86-64-v3`, but MSVC doesn't optimize intriniscs.)  Of course GCC or Clang optimize `__builtin_ctz` to the best available asm, but that's not portable to MSVC.

Comment: @PeterCordes The specification of [`_BitScanForward`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/bitscanforward-bitscanforward64?view=msvc-170) does not mention `bsf`. In fact, the intrinsic is also supported on ARM. The fact that MSVC does not generate `tzcnt` for it, when possible, is a matter of QoI and can be reported as a missed optimization to the compiler devs.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: Oh weird.  Intel documents it as an intrinsic for `bsf`.   https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,Other&ig_expand=796,440&text=bsf .  Fortunately this is all a moot point if either C++20 `std::countr_zero` is available, or if you're already using x86-64-v3 features and can use `_tzcnt_u32`.  Or if you know your input is non-zero you can use `_tzcnt_u32` even if it might run as `bsf`, if you're on MSVC or classic-ICC which let you use intrinsics for extensions you haven't enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I just use pointer math with SIMD intrinsics, or `&v[i]`, rather than `.begin()` / `.end()` iterators.  SIMD usage depends on contiguous storage of elements so we're not gaining any generality to collections where the iterator isn't equivalent to a `const int*`.

Your `reinterpret_cast` [is equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond) to `_mm512_load_si512(it)`, which is the alignment-required version.  (In optimized builds, the compiler will fold the load into a memory source operand for `vpcmpd` which doesn't enforce alignment.)  If your pointer might not be aligned, use `_mm512_loadu_si512`.

For vector widths narrower than 512, the `__m128i` / `__m256i` load/store intrinsics have less convenient definitions that don't take `void*` args, so you need `_mm256_loadu_si256( (const __m256i*) ptr_expression )`.  Intel changed over to `void*` for intrinsics introduced since about 2015, which includes everything new with AVX-512, but didn't retroactively change older intrinsics so we still need these noisy casts all over the place for working with integer vectors.

---

Yes, on Intel CPUs especially it's a good idea to align your pointers when using 512-bit vectors.  Ideally you can just use an aligned allocator for your `std::vector` so the data's always aligned. (If you only ever check from the start of the `std::vector`, not from some starting-point in the middle.)  Or if your data is *usually* aligned, often enough to make it not worth the overhead of any extra startup overhead for alignment.

But in this case, you can handle possible misalignment *very* cheaply: check the first vector, then align the pointer.  The first aligned vector will partially overlap the first vector if it wasn't aligned, but that's fine; you don't need to avoid checking the same element twice since you're not summing or anything.  This trick also works for copy-and-modify loops like `dst[i] = f(src[i])` where you never call it with `dst==src` to operate in place.

The same trick can be used for handling the end of the array, if the total array size is at least 1 vector large.  If small arrays are not rare in your intended use-case, consider 128-bit or 256-bit vectors for cleanup, potentially allowing this trick.  Or padding or aligning your arrays so it's safe to read past the end, masking away potential matches (set mask bits) from past where the array was supposed to end.  ([`bzhi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bzhi) is good for this, `_bzhi_u32`)

Given AVX-512, you definitely have BMI2 for `_tzcnt_u32`, so use that instead of compiler-specific intrinsics for BSF.  Or use C++20 `std::countr_zero`